# adsl modem/router with "ssh" server

Tags: ssh, router, wireless-router, adsl, tomato

Any recommendation re a good ADSL 2+ modem/router for home that has support for running an SSH server?  Would ideally want the ssh support to include:

- custom port can be defined (not standard ssh port)
- can use **public-private key pairs** for authentication (for extra security)
- can define a set of IP addresses which can use the ssh server

If there isn't anything available in the say $0-$500 range that covers this then what alternatives do you recommend, for example:

- install Tomato firmware perhaps
- sacrifice ssh at the perimeter & just port forward the ssh port to the computer you want to use (and then harden this computer as best possible)

---

I'll stick with this for the main question however as an aside ideally the device would also have (however these could be sacrificed in order to get my above-mentioned requirements)

- have wireless support (so I have everything in one)
- have a content filtering solution with updates available, working in a transparent proxy mode, with ability to define which internal devices are subject to it

Comment: Using public-private key pairs for SSH authentication is very common, but using true certificates is exceedingly UNcommon. You didn't really mean to say "certificates", did you?

Comment: yes - no doubt I did mean "public-private key pairs" then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a Tomato router (Asus RT-N16 ) + a modem with telnet access through the router (disregarding the modem's router functions) (Speedtouch 516).  Less than $200.